# Python selenium didn't find css element

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, xpath

I imported the code from Selenium Ide in python. The selenium test works fine without clicks on the item and scroll seamlessly clicks on an item.
HTML selenium code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://www.amazon.com/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=[alt=&quot;Deals in Books&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

But in Python does not work until you scroll-click to the to the desired item.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest, time, re

class Untitled(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://www.amazon.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_untitled(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.feed-carousel-control.feed-right > span.gw-icon.feed-arrow").click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.feed-carousel-control.feed-right > span.gw-icon.feed-arrow").click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.feed-carousel-control.feed-right > span.gw-icon.feed-arrow").click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.feed-carousel-control.feed-right > span.gw-icon.feed-arrow").click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[alt=\"Deals in Books\"]").click()

  def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
```

I tested in different selenium locators and xpath css and it works, but in python without scrolling click on the element is not working.

Comment: What does "not working", mean?  Nothing?  Error messages?  What have you tried?  What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you may [wait for the element to become visible](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[alt=\"Deals in Books\"]"))
)
element.click()
```

And, if you need to scroll to the element before clicking it, use the [Action Chains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains):

```
deals_in_books = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[alt=\"Deals in Books\"]")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(deals_in_books).click().perform()
```

And, if needed, [scroll into view of the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", deals_in_books)
```